# Upper-bound for bracketing number in terms of VC-dimension

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration, geometric-probability, learning-theory

Let $P$ be a probability distribution on a measurable space $\mathcal X$ (e.g;, some euclidean $\mathbb R^m$) and let $F$ be a class of funciton $f:\mathcal X \to \mathbb R$. Given, $f_1,f_2 \in F$, defined the bracket $[f_1,f_2]$ by
$$
[f_1,f_2] := \{f \in F \mid f_1(x) \le f(x) \le f_2(x) \,\forall x \in X\}.
$$
Also, let $X$ be a random object on $\mathcal X$ with distribution $F$, and for $p \in \{0\} \cup [1,\infty)$, define a pseudo-metric $d_F$ on $F$ by
$$
d_F^{(p)}(f_1,f_2) := \|f_1-f_2\|_{L_p(P)} = \begin{cases}
\mathbb P(f_1(X) \ne f_2(X)),&\mbox{ if }p = 0,\\
(\mathbb E[|f_1(X)-f_2(X)|^p)^{1/p},&\mbox{ if }1 \le p < \infty,\\
\underset{x \in \mathrm{supp}(P)}{\sup}|f_1(x)-f_2(x)|,&\mbox{ if }p=\infty.
\end{cases}
$$

> **Definition.** *Given $\varepsilon>0$, the $\varepsilon$-bracketing number of $F$ w.r.t $d^{(p)}_F$, denoted, $N_{[\,]}(F,L_p(P),\varepsilon)$, is the minimal number of brackets $[f_1,f_2]$ with $d_F^{(p)}(f_1,f_2) \le \varepsilon$, needed to cover $F$*.

> **Question.** *Suppose $\bar{F} := \{x \mapsto sign(f(x)) \mid f \in F\}$ has VC-dimension upper-bounded by $v$. What is a good upper-bound for $N_{[\,]}(F,L_p(P),\varepsilon)$ as a funciton of $v$, $\varepsilon$, and $p$ ?*

### Example: affine functions

Suppose $\mathcal X =$ eucldean $\mathbb R^m$, and $F_{\mathrm{affine}}$ is the set all functions $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ of the form $f(x) = x^\top w + b$, with $w \in \mathbb R^m$ and $b \in \mathbb R$. It is well-known that

$$
\mathrm{VCDim}(\bar{F}_{\mathrm{affine}})) = m + 1.
$$

### Example: affine functions

If $\mathcal X =$ eucldean $\mathbb R^m$, and $F_{\mathrm{affine}}$ is the set all functions $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ of the form $f(x) = x^\top w + b$, with $w \in \mathbb R^m$ and $b \in \mathbb R$, then it is well-known that
$$
\mathrm{VCDim}(\bar F_{\mathrm{affine}}) = m + 1.
$$

> **Question.** *What is a good upper-bound for $N_{[\,]}(F_{\mathrm{affine}},L_p(P),\varepsilon)$ as a function of $m$, $\varepsilon$, and $p$ ?*

Fix $R>0$, and consider the linear function class $F_0 \subseteq F_{\mathrm{affine}}$ defined by
$$
F_0 := \{x \mapsto x^\top w  \mid w \in \mathbb R^m,\, \|w\|_2 \le R\}.
$$
One can manually (and partially!) solve the problem like for this class like so. For any $p \in (1,2]$, we have

$$
\begin{split}
d^{(p)}_{F_0}(f_1,f_2) &:= (\mathbb E \|f_1(X)-f_2(X)|^p)^{1/p} = (\mathbb E|(w_1-w_2)^\top X|^p)^{1/p}\\
& = (\mathbb (E|(w_1-w_2)^\top X|^2)^{p/2})^{1/p} \le (\mathbb E|(w_1-w_2)^\top X|^2)^{1/2} = \|w_1-w_2\|_S\\
& \le \|w_1-w_2\|_2\cdot \sqrt{\|S\|_{op}},
\end{split}
$$
where $S := \mathbb E X X^\top$ (a psd matrix of order $m$), $\|z\|_S := \sqrt{z^\top S z}$, and $\|S\|_{op} := \sup_{\|z\|=1}z^\top S z$ is the spectral norm of $S$.

Now, since the unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^d$ can be covered with $(3/\varepsilon)^m$ balls of radius $\varepsilon$, we conclude that

> Forall $\varepsilon>0$, and $p \in (1,2]$, it holds that
> $$
> N_{[\,]}(F_0, L_p(P), \varepsilon) \le \left(\frac{R\sqrt{\|S\|_{op}}}{\varepsilon}\right)^m.
> $$

Presumably, the about bound is very crude for $p$ close to $1$.

Comment: I think a good MO question should in most cases admit a reasonably short answer. To consider a number of related questions may be good in a paper, but usually hardly so in one MO post. In this case, clearly your two questions can/should be separated. Also, quite a bit of editing is needed for the second question: (i) four lines of text are literally repeated; (ii) it is unclear what you mean by $\|w(f)\|_2$ and $b(f)$; (iii) $\otimes$ can have different meanings and should be avoided or defined. In your case, you are already using ${}^\top$; so, why do you need $\otimes$?

Comment: Advice taken. $X \otimes X := X X^\top $ is the outer product of the $m$-dimensional vector $X$ with itself. Also fixed issue related to $w(f)$ and $b(f)$.

Comment: Yes, here the meaning of $\otimes$ can be guessed from the context. But, as I said, why do you need $\otimes$, if you already have ${}^\top$?